# Static files on local machine not being published to IIS from visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015

this is about the first time I am trying to publish my first ASP.NET application to IIS on my local machine. 
I have gone through some guiding resources to be able to do that. I have installed both IIS and SQL Server Express on my local machine. I have been able to publish it and it is running on localhost/appname.
The problem however is that the static files - **CSS, JS and images are not being published** to IIS. So the application displays without styling, without images and without JavaScript. I have gone through Control Panel and ensured that **Static Content is checked** in the Commom Http Features category and still the problem persists. I have even **copied the files manually** from the development directory to the Content directory in IIS and still the problem persists.

I am running Windows 10, ASP.NET 4.6, Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition Update 1

I would really appreciate any guide to solving this problem.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that your static files are a part of the solution to have them included in the publish.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please, how do I ensure this? I assumed it they bare already part of the solution since I never excluded them from the project and it works from iis express